# Resultado erroneo C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un inconveniente en c++ estoy tratando de hacer un simple calculo usando POO pero el resultado es erroneo ni cercano al que deberia de ser :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class productos{

public:

productos(int x,int y){
x=n;
y=m;
cout<<x*y;
}
int producto1(){

    return n*m;//Usando esta funcion tampoco arroja el resultado
}



private:
int m; 
int n;
int mil;




};
int main()
{
    productos dos(2,2500);



return 0;
}
```

El resultado es:

```
-1074975852-1074975852
```

Tambien me daba error inicializando:

```
int m=2500;
```

Soy principiante en c++ y tengo otros programas de consola practicamente identicos quizas con mas funciones pero basicamente lo mismo.

¿Qué hice mal? y ¿cómo lo soluciono?

PD: probé ya con codeblocks sublime text y un compilador online y el resultado es el mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problema con variables sin inicializar

Estás cometiendo un error muy común y es hacer uso de una variable sin haber sido iniciada previamente a un valor.

```
void productos(int x, int y) {
  x = n;
  y = m;
  std::cout << x * y;
}
```

Como puedes ver aquí estás asignando a `x` y a `y` los valores de `n` y `m`, sobreescribiendo los valores que has pasado al constructor, pero éstos no tienen valores inicialmente, por lo que su contenido inicial es indeterminado.

```
private:
 int m;
 int n;
 int mil;
```

## Solución haciendo uso correcto de la clase

Si reordeno el código para que haga lo que deseas éste sería el resultado:

```
#include <iostream>

class productos {
 public:

  productos(int x, int y) {
    n = x;
    m = y;
    std::cout << "En el constructor: " << x * y << std::endl;
 }

  int producto1() {
    return n * m;
  }

 private:
  int m;
  int n;
  int mil;
};

int main() {
  /* Creo una instancia de productos pasando al constructor (2, 2500) */
  productos producto (2, 2500);
  /* Uso el método producto1 para calcular el resultado de la multiplicación */
  std::cout << "El resultado del producto es: " << producto.producto1() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución es:

```
En el constructor: 5000
El resultado del producto es: 5000
```

## Análisis de errores con valgrind

Resultados de valgrind de tu código:

```
==30015== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30015== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30015== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30015== Command: ./pruebas_stack
==30015== 
==30015== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30015==    at 0x4EBFCDE: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4008DB: productos::productos(int, int) (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015==    by 0x40084A: main (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015== 
==30015== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==30015==    at 0x4EBFBC3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4EBFD05: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4008DB: productos::productos(int, int) (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015==    by 0x40084A: main (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015== 
==30015== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30015==    at 0x4EBFBCF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4EBFD05: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4008DB: productos::productos(int, int) (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015==    by 0x40084A: main (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015== 
==30015== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30015==    at 0x4EBFD33: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==30015==    by 0x4008DB: productos::productos(int, int) (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015==    by 0x40084A: main (in ./pruebas_stack)
==30015== 
-251679360
==30015== 
==30015== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30015==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30015==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==30015== 
==30015== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30015== 
==30015== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30015== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==30015== ERROR SUMMARY: 20 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Donde resalto el significado de:

- *Use of uninitialised value of size 8*: **uso de un valor sin inicalizar de tamaño 8**.
- *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)*: **salto condicional depende de un valor sin inicializar**.

Resultados de valgrind tras corregir el problema:

```
==29964== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29964== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29964== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29964== Command: ./pruebas_stack
==29964== 
5000
==29964== 
==29964== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29964==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29964==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==29964== 
==29964== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29964== 
==29964== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29964== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la asignación dentro de `productos(int x, int y)` ya que estás asignando a éstas variables dentro de la función, quizás invertiste el orden de las variables; tienes 2 opciones:

1. En la función productos recibes las variables n y m `productos(int n; int m)`
2. En la función productos la dejas como la tienes (recibiendo x e y) pero modificas la asignación `n = x` y `m = y` e imprimes `cout<<n*m`

Yo lo hice con la forma 1:

```
#include <iostream>

class productos{

    public:

    productos(int n,int m){
        x=n;
        y=m;
        std::cout<< x*y;
    }

    private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    productos(2,2500);
    return 0;
}
```

Los valores que te arrojaba `-1074975852-1074975852` son porque tomaba valores de la memoria cuando realizabas asignaciones `x = n` y n no tenía ningún valor.

Comment: Mi +1, no vi tu respuesta cuando redacté la mía, me hubiera ahorrado tiempo :) Yo hubiera completado el código indicando el uso correcto de la clase.

Comment: con razon ese resultado si sabia que era valores de la memoria pero !! incluso pense en acceder a ellos con punteros pero ya bien ejecuto sin problemas Muchas gracias saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar los errores de inicialización de variables, los cuales no voy a detallar porque ya tienes otras respuestas en las que te comentan el problema, es preferible inicializar todas las variables miembro que sea posible en el apartado de inicialización dentro del constructor, me explico:

```
productos(int x, int y)
  : n(x), m(y)
{
  std::cout << "En el constructor: " << x * y << std::endl;
}
```

¿Por qué? Dos razones básicas:

- En el caso de inicializar clases evitas operaciones redundantes:

  ```
  struct Test
  {
    std::string a;

    // Aqui se hace
    // Llamada al constructor de std::string
    // Llamada al operador de asignación std::string = std::string
    Test(std::string const& var)
    {
      a = var;
    }

    // Aqui se hace
    // Llamada al constructor copia std::string(std::string const&)
    Test(std::string const& var)
      : a(var)
    { }
  };
  ```
- Como norma general, evita errores tontos:

  ```
  struct Test
  {
    int a;

    // Error de compilacion
    Test(int b)
      : b(a)
    { }

    // ok
    Test(int b)
      : a(b)
    { }

    // ok. Equivalente a this->a = a
    Test(int a)
      : a(a)
    { }
  };
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias me aclarastes ese tema !!!

Comment: Si sabia inicializar asi las variables y lo intente pero me arrojo error !! Ahora estoy mas entendido acerca de ello ...saludos!!!!